# Cannot pass parameter to select in MySQL 8.0

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-8.0

I'm writing a generic partitioning helper, and suddenly run into trouble.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `weekly_partition`(in schema_name_arg varchar(128), 
      in table_name_arg varchar(128), 
      in really bool)
    BEGIN
      declare start_date datetime;
      declare end_date datetime;
      if (not really) then
        select schema_name_arg, table_name_arg; -- works as expected
        select str_to_date(partition_name,'p%Y%m%d'), partition_name FROM 
          information_schema.partitions WHERE
          table_schema = table_schema_arg and
          table_name = table_name_arg; -- fails
      end if;
      -- more code here
    END
```

I'm getting an error Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'table_schema_arg' in 'where clause'

Sure it's not a column! It's an argument of the procedure! How do I tell MySQL to use argument?

Answer (score 1):

The correct procedure should be possibly:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `weekly_partition`(in schema_name_arg varchar(128), 
  in table_name_arg varchar(128), 
  in really bool)
BEGIN
  declare start_date datetime;
  declare end_date datetime;
  if (not really) then
    select schema_name_arg, table_name_arg; -- works as expected
    select str_to_date(partition_name,'p%Y%m%d'), partition_name FROM 
      information_schema.partitions WHERE
      table_schema = schema_name_arg and -- This is where it went wrong!
      table_name = table_name_arg; -- fails
  end if;
  -- more code here
END
```

You possibly had a typo in your code, because the parameters are `schema_name_arg` and `table_name_arg`.

You have/had `table_schema_arg`.

Comment: It's too hot here. My brains are melting. Thanks!